# Hystrix Threadpool Queue not working properly

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am using Hystrix library to process network calls. This is what I am using for thread pool configuration

```
HystrixThreadPoolProperties.Setter threadPropSetter = HystrixThreadPoolProperties.Setter();
threadPropSetter.withCoreSize(100);
threadPropSetter.withMaxQueueSize(1000);
```

I am creating a load of 1000 HytrixCommand objects using a common HytrixCommandKey and HytrixThreadPoolKey. But the thread pool executes the fallback logic after the first 100 threads are serviced, instead of using the threadpool queue. This can be solved by setting the threadpool,coreSize to 1000. But I am using java, and setting the coreSize to 1000 will spawn 1000 threads, which will consume a lot of system resource.

Can anyone provide a solution for this, so that the threadpool queue can actually queue the threads instead of just reverting to the fallback logic ?

Comment: Please post some code samples showing how you are creating and executing your commands. This looks like expected behaviour is you are not harvesting the results of your commands.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - The issue is resolved. I was actually running a loop for 1000 commands from my main method. So the jvm was terminating after the loop completion. Since the hystrix thread pool basically uses daemon threads, the queued threads were not being picked up after the jvm had terminated. So i just added a Thread.sleep() in my main method after loop completion, and now the queueing works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a Thread.sleep() in my main method so that the JVM doesnt terminate after the commands have been created and queued. Works fine now.